Boy finds skates & befriends girl
When I was a kid, I'd say about 8 years old (1997), I remember watching a movie I know it was on cable TV on HBO I believe or one of the movie channels. 
All I can remember from that movie is that it's about a boy that finds a pair of ice skates under a piece of wood in a small closet in his room. He takes the skates out at night and meets a girl - they have a good time then the boy needs to go home and promises the girl to come back the next day, and he does but when he goes back to meet the girl, years had passed between them the girl was older than the last time they saw each other. 
I wish I could tell you guys more but that's all I can remember. Can anyone identify this movie?

Sounds like it could maybe be Tom's Midnight Garden (1999)

Thank you so much that's the movie I was looking for! I have watched it 3 times today already!

Tom's Midnight Garden (1999)

When Tom Long's brother Peter gets measles he is sent to stay with his Uncle Alan and Aunt Gwen in a flat with no garden. An elderly and reclusive landlady, Mrs Bartholomew, lives upstairs. Because he may be infectious he is not allowed out to play, and feels lonely. Without exercise he is less sleepy at night and when he hears the communal grandfather clock strangely strike 13, he investigates and finds the small back yard is now a large sunlit garden. Here he meets another lonely child called Hatty, who seems to be the only one who can see him. They have adventures which he gradually realises are taking place in the 19th century. Each night when Tom visits, Hatty is slightly older and Tom begins to wonder about the nature of time and reality. In an attempt to discover what's going on Tom asks Hattie to leave her skates in a hidden place. When he goes back into the future he manages to find them. One night Hatty and Tom go out skating however Hatty begins to fall in love with a boy from her own time named Barty and Tom finds he is invisible to her. The next night Tom is unable to find the garden, running into rubbish bins from the modern day instead. Just before Tom returns home he meets Mrs Bartholomew, who is revealed to be an elderly Hatty.

